# Vectorized sum of different numbers of rows in a numpy array or pytorch tensor

Tags: python, numpy

I have an (2, 4, 3) numpy array

```
M = np.array([
    [[1, 10, 100],
     [2, 20, 200],
     [3, 30, 300],
     [4, 40, 400]],        
    [[5, 50, 500],
     [6, 60, 600],
     [7, 70, 700],
     [8, 80, 800]]
])
```

and I want to obtain a sum of m rows in the first subarray and n rows in the second subarray, let it would be 2, 3 and 4 rows in the first subarray and 1 and 2 rows in the second one

```
np.array([
    [[9, 90, 900]],

    [[11, 110, 1100]]
])
```

How to do that in vectorized way? Then how to obtain vectorized min/max over rows in the same case of different number of rows?

Comment: Do you mean `[9, 90, 900]` rather than `[9, 90, 100]`? I guess you'll do this with two operations that you concatenate back together. Each operation would select the rows and execute a sum. I would be surprised if someone could find a way to do this in a single operation.

Comment: yeah, sorry, made the correction

Comment: Can you show what you mean via for-loop or other "manual" calculation?

Comment: Like @DavidParks says, a single op likely won't do, but you can get close with something like `np.vstack((M[0, 1:4].sum(axis=0), M[1,:2].sum(axis=0)))`, playing with the index bounds as appropriate.

Comment: no single op required, but I need to avoid for loops

Comment: The row selection has to be a list of arrays (or lists), right?  The problem is you can't select different numbers of rows per subarray with one indexing operation.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem, the only solution which cames to my mind it to zero out the rows which I don't need, sum the other, and then divide each subarray to the number of selected rows to get the mean

but maybe other solutions? if I would like to get min or max it would be a bit ugly

Comment: @hpaulj. The first problem is to define how you select rows. The recommendation I made is to settle for `np.where` syntax since it's compatible with normal indexing and just makes everything easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `np.add.reduceat` after applying the appropriate index. In fact, you need to define your index clearly first. I recommend using the normal fancy indexing format that is returned by functions like `np.where`:

```
p = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1] # Which plane to grab
r = [1, 2, 3, 0, 1] # Which row to grab in that plane
m = M[p, r, :]

>>> m
array([[  2,  20, 200],
       [  3,  30, 300],
       [  4,  40, 400],
       [  5,  50, 500],
       [  6,  60, 600]])
```

Now you can easily determine the cut-points in `r` based on changes in `p`:

```
splits = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(p)) + 1]

>>> splits
array([0, 3])
```

And apply:

```
>>> np.add.reduceat(m, splits, axis=0)
array([[   9,   90,  900],
       [  11,  110, 1100]])
```

For a given `p` and `r`, you can use a one-liner, which is not completely illegible (IMO):

```
np.add.reduceat(M[p, r, :], np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(p))], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

My own's take is via linear algebra and `einsum`

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([
    [[1, 10, 100],
     [2, 20, 200],
     [3, 30, 300],
     [4, 40, 400]],
    
    [[5, 50, 500],
     [6, 60, 600],
     [7, 70, 700],
     [8, 80, 800]]
])

w = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

>>> np.einsum("bw,bwj->bj", w, M)

array([[   9,   90,  900],
       [  14,  140, 1400]])
```